# Android - Should I use multiple activities or multiple content views

Tags: xml, android, layout, android-activity

i'm new with android.

I'm working on an application using xml layouts.
I wish to know which is better:
 1. Use few activities and change its contentview
 2. Use an activity for each 'view' needed

If both works, in which case which option would be better?

thx a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072244/android-what-is-better-multiple-activities-or-switching-views-manually I believe that the answer there is comprehensive and so linking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule would be to use multiple activities. That's the way it's meant to be and you won't be breaking navigation (e.g. going to the previous "screen" by pressing back button).