# Start a new activity or setContentView?

Tags: android

Is it better to start a new activity or just set a new content view in Android?

I usually start a new activity when I have to change the whole environment, but IMHO I think it's too onerous when I need to keep the other activity alive in the background.

On the other hand, I could have a single activity and just change the layout when I have to set a new environment.

Which is the better way and why?

Comment: This question has already been answered, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072244/android-what-is-better-multiple-activities-or-switching-views-manually

Comment: which is the better way when I do something that changes the whole environment of my app, for example clicking a button appears a list of images... well, I have to start a new activity every time, or I just set the content view, keeping only the main activity alive?? works in both cases, but with the setContentView I avoid to create a new activity, but I don't know if this method is acceptable or there are further alternatives ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern one activity, multiple views. Advantages and disadvantages.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757418/pattern-one-activity-multiple-views-advantages-and-disadvantages)

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'Pattern one activity, multiple views. Advantages and disadvantages' on stack-overflow and look for the answer by @CommonsWare