# Using Back Button in Google Chrome App in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-activity, back-button

I was reading about the difference between a "view" and an "activity" and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072244/android-what-is-better-multiple-activities-or-switching-views-manually?rq=1), I discovered that the "Back button" is used to switch to the previous ACTIVITY.
[image: Back-button]

Applying this concept to the Google Chrome browser app on Android:
I somehow know that each tab in Chrome is a separate activity (right?). But what now confuses me is that when I am on a particular chrome tab, and I press the back button on my smartphone, it takes me to the previous page on the same tab. Does that mean that each "page" on every tab is a separate activity, and that whenever I open a website page on an existing tab, the webpage gets pushed into the stack as a running activity?

*** the aim of this question is to help me better understand the concept of activity and activity-stack on android ***

Answer (score 0):

This might help to understand the distinction between **Activities** and **Tasks** a bit more: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html