# Making the user follow specific steps

Tags: java, android

Am not sure if the title describes what I want. Am developing an App on Android where kids start a new empty drawing project and finish with a full drawing at the end by dragging different shapes from a list of shapes that I created for the App. My problem is that I dont know how am going to follow the kid steps.

The kid is supposed to read a message in each step and try to apply it and then click on a next button to view the next step.

I want to make sure that he do exactly what the message is saying in order to view the next step.

Theoretically, how is this applied in Java ?  If for example, there would be 20 steps how can I make the app follow up with him and make sure he is doing the right thing

Comment: that´s too broad to answer it. If You need help, You should describe more exact how they should drag the shapes. For example, they have a start point and an end point, like take the shape and put it inside the the other shape. Then You could get xy position and check if they reached their goal....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Actually they start with a plain white window and the App keep giving them instructions to start drawing with  different shapes. The shapes are like birds, tress, ...etc. When they finish a whole drawing is made of the steps they followed.

Comment: If I understood correctly. Your message will be something like "Drag a (shape) to the (region)". You can implement class `Region` which will "know" if the correct shape is in it.

Comment: that´s a good way, Region

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to create a wizard. In Java use a MVC libray Spring-MVC or if its android you can use similar approach. Basically you want steps and views while saving the state - typical MVC pattern. Have a model object that is passed along to the views. Each view will have portions of the model that it can read/write to.

Android -refer to [WizarDroid](http://wizardroid.codepond.org/).
Spring - [AbstractWizardFormController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractWizardFormController.html) will help

Comment: sounds like the solution am looking for. Am going to give it a try. appreciate your help

Comment: Glad it helped - do read this interesting post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072244/android-what-is-better-multiple-activities-or-switching-views-manually?lq=1

Comment: I red a lot about the MVC pattern but couldn't actually know how to implement this for my project. It seems not related to what I am looking for. In my case, the XML file will act as the View, the main activity is the Controller, Finally the Model which I dont know how am going to use it!!. Should I write my steps that should be followed in the model ? I dont really know how to implement it on my project