# android ui - is there any android wizard framework around?

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is any android wizard framework around which helps implementing a wizard like setup sequence. Surely it can be implemented from the ground with not too much pain (for example one discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013469/make-a-wizard-like-application-in-android)) yes as this seems a quite standard need I hope there is already some support framework for this available.

Thanks buddies

martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer this - but not in the affirmative. There is nothing in the core API, neither is there anything in ActionBarSherlock, and I've failed to find anything remotely useful anywhere else.

I've ended up developing my own wizard framework on the back of ABS but at the moment its so heavily intertwined with my own app (and my other framework code) that it isn't in a state to put up as a public repo on github (which is my longer term plan).

If you decide to go your own way I recommend you start from ActionBarSherlock and use a tabbed view with fragments. Its easy to put together and the end user can use the tabs, or swiping, or buttons (if you provide them) to  navigate from step to step. It may also be possible to hide the tabs if you don't want them visible (but they do give the user an idea of what is coming up which can be helpful). Have a look at the fragments sample app, specifically the "Tabs and Pager" sample. ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdaptor are your friends. You can download ABS and the samples [from the Action Bar Sherlock site](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)