# What is a proper way to get data of multiple Activity in a single Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 5 Activities in my App. Each Activity having some data. I need all previous Activity data in last Activity. All previous Activity is a kind of Form. User fill the data and move to next Activity and last Activity displays all previous Activity's data.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013469/make-a-wizard-like-application-in-android

Comment: You can use a static singleton class like Application

Comment: Definnitely +1 for a singleton globalData class. By far the easiest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

- Use of Intents and save the data like `putString(...)`:
  Which isn't really nice because you have to temporarilly save the data of each Intent in the Activity and move them further with the next Intent.
- Use a class for your data and pass it through the Activities per Intent:
  This way you pass the instance of the class to the Activities to write/read your data. But this class needs the Parcelable / Serializable interface
- Use of a static class:
  You can access this class in every Activity and write/read like you want.
- Use a Bundle with the Intent:
  Save all your data in a Bundle and pass it to the Activities.
- Think about your design and use Fragments:
  Have one Activity with 5 Fragments. Every Fragment saves/reads the data from the Activity.

Best approach would be to use a Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

If you want to  add data for every activity and carryforward it to next activity then it's better to pass data with `bundle`.

Bundles are better in a scenario, when data is comparatively small and where you just want to pass data to next activity and don't want to store the data for future.

**Option 2:**

You can use `Sharedprefrences`. Better to use when data is to be stored for future.

**Option 3:**

If you have more records and you want it to be in a structured manner, and to be stored for future then `Sqlite`database is obvious.

Above to options are in case if you want to use your data to use very frequently and it is not structured.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent`

FirstActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key_value", string); 
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("key_value");
```

Or if you need the data to stay longer, and you can reuse it after the application is killed, you can use `SharedPrefrences`

Place the data in some `Activity`

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("ValueOne", "SomeValue" );
 editor.commit();
```

Retrieve data from shared preference in any `Activity`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String prefString = prefs.getString("ValueOne", null);
```

Comment: Instead of passing data from one Activity to another, Can I have all data directly to the Activity where I want to display all data?

Comment: @SonusinghChauhan yes, you can use the SharedPreferences in order to do that.