# Creating a Wizard in an Android app

Tags: android, wizard

I am building an app for Android where I have a navigation drawer with 3 buttons, each leading to a separate screen. On one screen is another button that, when clicked, will start a wizard like "control" that has 4 screens, and you need to move to the next and previous in each one. The last screen has a submit button where I process input from the other screens in the wizard. What is the best way to do this in android? I am coming from the .NET world and I looked around for a wizard control of some sort, but to no avail. Any ideas are helpful!

Comment: You could use a `ViewFlipper` with the 4 screens in it. Then at the end when pressing submit, get the info from all the fields. Or just page through different screens. Or page through different (alert)dialogs.

Comment: Interesting. Another requirement is that I use buttons for Next and Previous, as well as Submit. Can the ViewFlipper do this, or is it swipe only?

Comment: Yes, just link the buttons to the call `ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0)` rather than page through automatically. Monitor the current one, so you can set the right view to display. There are pros and cons to using a single screen or multiple screens here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013469/make-a-wizard-like-application-in-android?rq=1

Comment: In case you want to use popup style, it is also possible. Inside popup you can use either flipper, as Doomsknight mentioned, or you can also create many popups, switch between them and save data to some kind of custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open source android lib [WizarDroid](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid/)